# SharePoint Online CSOM CAML query problem in view

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

I have a pages library in sharepoint online with 2 views.

Custom view - (I have added a condition in the view based on a content type) -
 contains 500 items, It has got 100 items where title starts with "abc"

Default view - It has 4 items and all items have title starting with "abc" 
(Don't know why it is showing only 4 items, there is no filter condition and I am expecting all 504 items to appear in the view) - but shows only 4 items

I want to write a CAML query in CSOM on custom view where title begins with "abc"

```
<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <BeginsWith>
                <FieldRef Name="Title" />
                <Value Type="Text">abc</Value>
            </BeginsWith>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Query executes fine but shows only 4 items, looks like it is showing items from default view but I want to show items from custom view.

I can load my custom view and use view query

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.View view = oList.Views.GetByTitle("Custom View");
                rentalSiteClientContext.Load(view);
                rentalSiteClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                query.ViewXml = view.ViewQuery
                ListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(query);
                rentalSiteClientContext.Load(collListItems);
                rentalSiteClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

this is still returning 4 items.

Comment: any help please..

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as you have not posted the complete code so I tried to write a console app.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;    
namespace ConsoleApplication    
{
    class Program    
    {    
        static void main(string[] args)    
        {    
            using (ClientContext ctx=new ClientContext("http://siteurl"))    
            {   
                ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");    
                Web web = ctx.Web;    
                ctx.Load(web, w=>w.Lists);
                List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List");//Load list    
                ctx.Load(list, l => l.Views);    
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();    
                CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();    
                ListItemCollection itemColl = null;    
                View view = list.Views.GetByTitle("Your view");//enter view name
                ctx.Load(view, vw => vw.ViewQuery);    
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();    
                query.ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query>{0}</Query></View>", view.ViewQuery); <--- Place actual query here
                itemColl = list.GetItems(query);    
                ctx.Load(itemColl);    
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();    
            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: are you saying to replace string.Format("<View><Query>{0}</Query></View>", view.ViewQuery); with my query?

Comment: I am using this query now string.Format("<View><Query>{0}</Query></View>", "<Where />");  but still getting 4 results, it should return all items in that view but it is returning items from default view.  My question is where that view is being used in query??

Comment: Can you try using your actual query in place of `view.ViewQuery`?

Comment: yes just for testing I am trying to get all items and I used this query string.Format("<View><Query>{0}</Query></View>", "<Where />"); this should return me all items but it also returns 4 items.

Comment: I tried this code its working for me. Try the code on some other list.